# How to display dark edges over lighter ones in Matlab plots?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

I have the following Matlab plot representing a graph. I would like to display the darker on top of the lighter ones in such a way the lighter edges don't modify the darker when crossing them. How could I do?

Edit: the Matlab code for reproduce the example is the following

```
plot(G, 'XData', Xcoords, 'YData', Ycoords,'NodeLabel',{}, 'MarkerSize', 7,...
 'Linewidth',1.6, 'EdgeCData', G.Edges.Weight)
  colormap(flipud(gray(40)));
  colorbar('southoutside');
  caxis([min(G.Edges.Weight) max(G.Edges.Weight)])
 axis off
```

where the weights of the edges are encoded in G.Edges.Weight

To reproduce the effect (with a smaller graph), you can try with the following code:

```
A= zeros(4,4);
A(1,[2 3 4])=1;
A(2,4)=0.04;
A(2,[1 3])=1;
A(3,[2 1 4])=1; 
A(4,2)=0.04;
A(4,[3 1])=1;

Xcoords=[1 2 2 1]';
Ycoords= [1 1 2 2 ]';

G= graph(A);% base toolbox

figure()
plot(G, 'XData', Xcoords, 'YData', Ycoords, 'NodeLabel',{}, 'MarkerSize', 7,...
    'LineWidth', 3.8, 'EdgeCdata', G.Edges.Weight)
colormap(flipud(gray(40)));
colorbar('southoutside'); caxis([0 1]);
axis off
```

It seems that is the ordering of the edges that decide who is on top. For instance, if the weight 0.04 is assigned to the other crossing edge (A(1,3)=A(3,1)) the effect is not visible since the edge A(2,4)=A(4,2) cames after.
[image: Graph]

Comment: Please show a sample of how you generated the graph. It's hard to help you without seeing any reproducible code. In general though, draw the light edges first, so the dark ones can go over them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes sure, I have edited the question

Comment: Can you show some sample code to create `G`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the graph is learning through an algorithm. I have the learned adjacency and Laplacian matrix. Do you know how to load the entire graph here?

Comment: You don't need to load the entire thing here, just provide a small sample with fixed data that reproduces the issue. All you need to show is a few intersecting edges.

Comment: Give me 1 minute, I will generate it

Comment: Edited question. It seems that is the ordering of the edges that decide who is on top. For instance, if the weight 0.04 is assigned to the other crossing edge (A(1,3)=A(3,1)) the effect is not visible since the edge A(2,4)=A(4,2) cames after. If you look at the G.Edges.Weight property, you can see there is a fixed ordering of the edge weights and thus also in the plotting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the edge table in MATLAB's `graph` class seems pretty tightly dependent on position in the graph's adjacency matrix, which is inherently impossible to contrive in a way that guarantees some arbitrary edge order. So I think you only have two options:

1. Write your own graph plotting routine; then you can control the plotting order however you like because it's your own software design.
2. Manipulate MATLAB's graph plotting output using the undocumented primitives it creates.

The second option is possible by noting that the plotted `GraphPlot` object has a `LineStrip` object in its `NodeChildren` which is responsible for drawing all the relevant edges. Because you're using a grayscale color map, the RGB data in this object is all you need to figure out how its vertices need to be ordered to get the right plot order.

First, store the plotted result in `P` and set `EdgeAlpha` to `1` so the graph is plotted

> in such a way the lighter edges don't modify the darker when crossing them

```
P = plot(G, 'XData', Xcoords, 'YData', Ycoords, 'NodeLabel',{}, 'MarkerSize', 7,...
    'LineWidth', 3.8, 'EdgeCdata', G.Edges.Weight, 'EdgeAlpha',1);
colormap(flipud(gray(40)));
colorbar('southoutside'); caxis([0 1]);
axis off
```

Then find the `LineStrip` created in the drawing process:

```
drawnow
s = P.NodeChildren(arrayfun(@(o) isa(o,'matlab.graphics.primitive.world.LineStrip'), P.NodeChildren));
```

The new order of the vertices in `s` can then be determined from its `ColorData`, which must then be applied to both the `ColorData` and `VertexData` properties to reorder the edges without anything else changing:

```
[~,idx] = sortrows(s.ColorData','desc');
set(s, 'VertexData',s.VertexData(:,idx),  'ColorData',s.ColorData(:,idx));
```

This will be liable to be overridden by any further redrawing that takes place and being undocumented functionality comes with no guarantees as to how it will behave – but superficially it seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for your reply. From what I see, the only change is that now the white edge is on top the black one in the example graph with one crossing. This is due to the EdgeAlpha properties set to 1. The others lines of code seem not to change the properties. I tried inspecting the LineStrip object but it is empty, also from the command line it doesn't produce any output. Moreover, when digiting `P.` the automatic compilation does not show `NodeChildren` yet `Childen`. However doing as you said, it did not throw any error but it does not display the desided result. Do you know more?

Comment: I misunderstood a line in your question and thought you wanted lighter colors on top. Reversing the sort order, as per my edited answer, reverses this. `NodeChildren` is a hidden property of graphics objects and `LineStrip` has no public properties so your results with variable inspection are correct. You need to query hidden properties directly to see them, and use methods like `metaclass` to discover them.

Comment: I tried, but the effect does not change for the simple graph of 4 nodes... Do you know something?

Comment: You might want to try to set the 'zorder' property of the edges.

Comment: @Alberto no, that's a bit tricky. Running the code in your question and then the code in my answer gives me a plot with a dark edge on top of a light one. This is in MATLAB R2018b; are you on something older?

Comment: @CrisLuengo are you thinking of a different platform? As far as I know, there's no such thing as a `zorder` property on any class that ships with MATLAB. And anyway, the individual edges in graph plots are never exposed as individual objects with their own properties at all, again at least as far as I know.

Comment: @Will I'm using MATLAB R2017b, and the method sort gives me an an empty idx array, from what I see... And also using descending order doesn't change..

Comment: @Alberto have you been running the code above all in one go? I've realised the objects in the `NodeChildren` property depend on the graph plot to have finished drawing to be initialised. I was running each stage separately from the command line, but if running all at once you need to call `drawnow` before accessing the primitives in `NodeChildren`. If this doesn't solve the problem, though, then you will have to do some exploration of how things work in R2017b. That's the pitfall of relying on undocumented features - there's no guarantee how things will work from on version to the next.

Comment: @Will by using `drawnow`, I have the desired effect. Thank you so much, really. It still remains a little issue, the darker edges stays on top of the lighter ones as long as I don't zoom on the plot. After zooming, all return as before. Do you know how to completely resolve this?

Comment: @Alberto yes, this was the kind of fragility I was worried about in the last paragraph of the answer. The `GraphPlot` object has a hidden event `MarkedClean` which I *think* fires every time something that redraws the primitives occurs. So you could make the code that reorders the edge vertices run every time this fires using `addlistener`. I'm not sure if this will disturb the zoom process at all but it's worth a try

Comment: @Will It happens by the way also when I simply save the image, not only when zooming. By the way, thank you very much for your help and your availability

Comment: @will Coming back to this question, could you please indicate me how to enable this eventlistener on the MarkedClean event?

Comment: @Albus - as I said, using [`addlistener`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html). Something like `addlistener(P,"MarkedClean",@ReorderEdges)`.